# NSDictionary selector error NSString with spaces

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsstring, nsdictionary

```
-(void)messageSend:(NSString *)message;
{
NSLog(@"messageSend");
urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://someaddress/message/send?from=%@&msg=%@&latitude=0&longitude=0",appDelegate.userName,message];
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[self request:urlString]];
NSLog(@"Dictionary response");
if ([dictionary count] > 0)
{
    if ([[dictionary objectForKey:@"send"] isEqualToString:@"OK"] )
    {
        NSLog(@"envio de mensagem de %@ Ok: %@",appDelegate.userName,message);
    }
}
[urlString release];
[dictionary release];
}
```

Gives an error of `-[__NSArrayM getObjects:andKeys:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`. After some testing with `NSLogs`, the line

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[self request:urlString]];
```

is the culprit, witch is calling this method:

```
-(NSDictionary *)request:(NSString *)requestString
{
url =[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:requestString];
request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:10];
error = [[NSError alloc] init];
responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
[responseData retain];
NSString *tempString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableDictionary *tempDict= [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
if (request)
{
    Parser *parser = [[Parser alloc] init];
    tempDict = [parser readXMLString:tempString];
    for (id key in tempDict)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@ is %@",key,[tempDict objectForKey:key]);
    }
}
[url release];
[error release];
[responseData release];
[tempString release];
return tempDict;
}
```

And it happens when the string of the message has spaces.
But it was not happening before.

Comment: Does `readXMLString` always return a dictionary?

Comment: Clearly, readXMLString did not return an NSDictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is the line `tempDict = [parser readXMLString:tempString]`. In fact, this means your previous creation of a `[[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease]` is pointless, as it will just be overwritten by the return value of `[parser readXMLString:tempString]`. In any case, it appears the `-readXMLString:` method is returning an `NSArray` instead of an `NSDictionary`.

Comment: That line creates a leak, but leaks don't cause a crash. It is not certain (but likely) whether it is the cause of the problem. We don't know what a Parser does, or what readXMLString: returns or is supposed to return (what if it returns an `id`?). For all I know, readXMLString: could be the real culprit.

Comment: @Rudy: That line does not create a leak. The object is autoreleased. It's just sloppy and wasteful.

Comment: Correct. The autorelease fell off the screen, so I missed it, but I could see it after scrolling. <g>

Comment: Well, i'm not with my mac here, but i can say that i designed readXMLString to return a NSDict, and parser takes the string thats a xml, breaks it down and stores in the to-be-returned NSDict.

I will recheck my allocs and releases, thanks.

By the way, i set it to autorelease since i cant release it before returning obviouslly... or is there something im forgetting?

Comment: Actually, it`s not that it was returning an array. but i was declaring an NSDict but initializing as an NSArray...problem solved!

Answer (score 2):

I see a few peculiarities:

```
error = [[NSError alloc] init];
responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

Usually, you simply do:

```
NSError *error = nil;
responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

The error variable will be filled with the address of an autoreleased error object if there is an error, otherwise it should remain nil. Do not allocate one yourself, since you could be releasing the wrong one (the one returned by the `sendSynchronousRequest:`etc. method). This *could* cause an over-release at the end of your method.

```
NSMutableDictionary *tempDict= [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
if (request)
{
    Parser *parser = [[Parser alloc] init];
    tempDict = [parser readXMLString:tempString];
```

- In the if-block, you are overwriting the pointer to the `tempDict` you just created. That is a memory leak (but not the cause of your problem). **Update**: the one you created is autoreleased. No leak.
- You also don't `release` the `Parser` used in the if-block (and local to it).
- You never check the value of error to see if actually an error occurred. As I said, you should set `error` to `nil` before the invocation of `sendSynchronousRequest:etc.` and then check if it is still `nil`, and if not, react accordingly:

  ```
  if (error)
  {
      // error handling
  }
  ```

What is the return type of `[parser readXMLString: tempString];`? Could it be an array and not a dictionary? E.g. an array of dictionaries?

Add an

```
NSLog(@"%@", tempDict);
```

in `request:`, before you return the `tempDict`. What does it show?

The `getObjects:AndKeys:` is probably called in `-[NSMutableDictionary initWithDictionary:]`. Apparently the *real* type of the dictionary returned by `request:` is not a dictionary, it is an array. See what I wrote above.

Comment: @ NSError: i seem to be to worried about initializing objects like
that, so i don't know when i can initialize the way you put it, i'll see to it.

@ memory leak: I though i was creating a dictionary, and then putting information on it?

@ error check: if i do a 

    NSLog("error: %@",error); 

i would print the error right?

@ readXMLString:: it returns a dictionary. I a afraid i MAY had made it return an mutable
one =/

Thats it, i'm sorry i can't give you THAT concrete info since im not at home right now.